# How do I get the name of a child Python class when a mocked parent class method is called?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking, python-unittest, pyside2

I have a tonne of dialogs and wizards in a large QT/Python app but can't determine which child class triggers the parent's exec_ method. Is there anyway to do this using mock, or any other library? I can find it via debug of course but I want a programmatic way to do it.

```py
import mock
from PySide2 import QtWidgets

class CustomDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    pass


class AnotherCustomDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog) :
    pass


def launch_custom_dialog() :
    dlg = CustomDialog() 
    dlg.exec_() 


with mock.patch.object(QtWidgets.QDialog, 'exec_') as mock_dialog:
    test_which_calls_launch_custom_dialog()
    if mock_dialog.called:
        # How do I find the name of the child? I.e. CustomDialog
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling this yourself:

```py
def launch_custom_dialog() :
    dlg = CustomDialog()    # or could be any of your custom dialogs
    dlg.exec_()
    return dlg
```

Then you can create your own intermediate base class:

```py
class CustomDialogBase(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def exec_(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.note_caller = self
        return super().exec_(*args, **kwargs)

class CustomDialog(CustomDialogBase):
    pass
class AnotherCustomDialog(CustomDialogBase) :
    pass
```

Now you can examine which child class it was:

```py
dlg = launch_custom_dialog()
print(dlg.note_caller)
```

Comment: This is a great response. Thanks. It does answer my simplistic example, however in reality the dlg instantiation is happening deep within subcalls of a test case so I cannot easily grab its instance. I was hoping there would be a way within mock itself to access the class of a mocked function.